# Appending div's in certain areas within unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append, clone

I currently have a standard unordered list, which acts as an accordion menu for my site navigation ([Here's my markup in full](http://pastebin.com/SsrfXjLm)). I want to provide a more enhanced navigation for browsers that support the new features I will be using (css 3d transforms). For this to work, I need to amend the structure of my code slightly to match the output of the following (i.e. append/clone elements into the structure):

```
<!-- mp-menu -->
<nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
<div class="mp-level"> <!--NEW APPENDED ELEMENT-->
    <ul id="demo1" class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Devices</a>
            <div class="mp-level">
                <h2>Devices</h2> <!--NEW CLONED ELEMENT-->
                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a> <!--NEW APPENDED ELEMENT-->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Mobile Phones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Televisions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cameras</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Magazines</a>
            <div class="mp-level">
                <h2>Magazines</h2> <!--NEW CLONED ELEMENT-->
                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a> <!--NEW APPENDED ELEMENT-->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">National Geographic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Scientific American</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I want to append the new elements if its possible but this doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
$( "#mp-menu" ).append('<div class="mp-level">');
```

To clone the Level 1 link into a H2, I've tried but no luck:

```
$( "#mp-menu ul li .mp-level" ).clone('<h2>Devices</h2>');
```

Comment: bit confused.. can you show us how your final output should be ?

Comment: @bipen The starting code I have is the link off to pastebin but the code in my question is the result I want. See the comments identifying the elements I need appended/cloned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is not the same as string concatenation where you can just add bit and pieces of strings to a dom structure.

For the first part you can use [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)

```
$('#mp-menu').wrapInner('<div class="mp-level" />');
```

For the second part use the below [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$( "#mp-menu ul li .mp-level" ).prepend(function(){
    return '<h2>' + $(this).prev().text()+ '</h2> <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>';
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z5nPM/)

Comment: This is great, however I need to insert a DIV with classname .mp-level to wrap around every second level UL and the newly inserted H2 and back links (if they exist). How might I edit your answer to do this?

Comment: are you saying `<a href="#">Magazines</a>
            <div class="mp-level">` is not there in the source html

Comment: The links are present (i.e. <a href="#">Magazines</a>) but the <div class="mp-level"> are not. Your second fiddle has nailed it. Thanks!